# Is there a function to count (only the) rows where the values in column `A` are greater than corresponding value in column `B`?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Scores in a [STAR Score](https://www.starvoting.us) voting election:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Candidate A | Candidate B | Candidate C | Is A > B? | Is A > C? | Is B > C? | Is C > B? |
| **2** | 5 | 3 | 2 | T | T | T | F |
| **3** | 0 | 4 | 3 | F | F | T | F |
| **4** | 2 | 3 | 5 | F | F | F | T |
| **5** | 3 | 4 | 4 | T | F | F | F |
| **6** |  |  | **Tally** | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| **7** |  |  | **%** | 50% | 25% | 50% | 25% |
| **8** | Score A = 10 | Score B = 14 | Score C = 14 |  |  |  |  |

In practice I will have 5 or more Candidates and many rows of data (STAR votes). This is a small example, I can create a column, like Columns **D, E, F & G** to do this for each comparison I need to make and tally (eg how many times in this range of data is the cell in column **A** greater than corresponding cell in column **B**?) but with a larger dataset I might end up with (n-1)! columns *where n is the number of 'Candidates'*. I want to compact it into a single formula in a single cell **D6**, and then copy it to **E6**, **F6** & **G6** if this possible without VBA or whatever.

So I'm looking for a function that would CountIf for each row in the range if the value in a specified column referenced is greater than some other referenced column in the range referenced (or first and last columns to avoid using arguments to locate the columns).

I guess a SumIF or CountIF type of function but with more flexible arguments, i.e. without a hard coded comparison argument like `">" 4`, but a reference to the data in each row itself, so the function would tabulate column D and then count the True values for me.

hard to explain but I come across this kind of problem from time to time… I guess I could do in Excel with Lambda functions but I haven't learnt how to do them in Excel yet.

Comment: sorry, the table at the top previews find in the Editor but not on this page. don't know why.

Comment: Please choose a platform, spamming tags usually gets the question closed as too broad.  The answer is likely to be different depending on the platform being used.

Comment: In other words, Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets is not Apple Numbers.

Comment: ok. I'm working in Sheets but I think Excel is more likely to get a response.

Comment: I just came across a similar Q to this (which got closed down like these kind of Excel questions often do) and it's suggesting the flexibility of SUMPRODUCT formula is what I'm going to need. Not sure on answer yet though.

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that an Excel solution will work in Sheets. So, please use appropriate tags.

Comment: yep, as my tags may have indicated, I have all three apps and can move this to any of them where it will work. Excel tags are fine.

Comment: you use the inverse of C and B but not A and B or A and C, why?

Comment: brevity in the example. In the case of this election, columns B and C have the two highest scores, so in the STAR voting system they both go into run-off where preferences are counted (which is why I need to compare scores for these too columns) normally I wouldn't know that up front, though I could compute it. so in this election B is preferred by more voters than C, so B wins and C comes second. There's actually a tool for this as an add-on for google Forms but I couldn't find it's output so was trying to replicate it.

Comment: if you edit the question you will see it, perfectly. there's some anomaly with the finished version not parsing correctly in SO. I created this example directly in StackOverflow. I'll recreate and link though.

Comment: thx for fixing the rendering @ScottCraner

Comment: to be complete there should be, and "B > A"

Comment: I've worked out a different way to solve this problem, because I can determine the first and second scorers and create a reference to those columns with RANK function or something like that. Then only compare the 1st scorer's value with the 2nd scorer's value for each individual vote (so I only need X > Y ad Y > X where X is 1st place and Y is 2nd place in the scores)

More generally I've always wanted to be able to do the things that I now think SUMPRODUCT does without resorting to scripting, so I'll attempt to answer this question that way.

Comment: ok here's an excel sheet you can download. this has a couple of edge case bugs but mostly works. I have four examples of different result method pathways.
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au_O3Z-fCOOUggzArRooR64Fqeey

Answer (score 2):

```
=ArrayFormula({A2:A5>B2:B5, A2:A5>C2:C5, B2:B5>C2:C5, C2:C5>B2:B5})
```

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE({A2:A5>B2:B5, A2:A5>C2:C5, B2:B5>C2:C5, C2:C5>B2:B5}*1), SEQUENCE(4, 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

```
=ArrayFormula((1/SUM(
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE({A2:A5>B2:B5, A2:A5>C2:C5, B2:B5>C2:C5, C2:C5>B2:B5}*1), SEQUENCE(4, 1, 1, 0)))))*
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE({A2:A5>B2:B5, A2:A5>C2:C5, B2:B5>C2:C5, C2:C5>B2:B5}*1), SEQUENCE(4, 1, 1, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: well done, that's impressive! (if a bit hard to parse like so much Excel formulaic stuff)

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Spreadsheet [linked](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au_O3Z-fCOOUggzArRooR64Fqeey) to avoids making multiple array calculations in a single cell and uses the fact that in STAR voting the highest and second highest scorers are taken to a run-off where preferences are counted. Provided more for explanation of the concepts than answering the OP.

That means this preference comparison only needs to take place between two candidates, not every combination of two candidates. Takes a lot of the pain out of it.

This spreadsheet mostly works, doesn't seem to like zero scores for some reason… gives N/A in the IF A > B formulas. It has some examples of how different results are produced in different circumstances.

**[[Excel Spreadsheet link.]](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au_O3Z-fCOOUggzArRooR64Fqeey)**

[image]